# How can I keep the tooltip active on apexcharts?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I want to keep the tooltip active when I click on a point in the scatter graph, but I still can't.

I understand that I should use this function, but I cannot keep the tooltip active, because I only have scope to the event, but I can't get to the tooltip and activate it.

```
markers: {
  onClick: function (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```